# Visual Basics - Range selection method using column numbers not letters

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have dynamically changing Column numbers. I need to select 2 cells using that column number. As I cannot use cells command to select more than one cell and i cannot use Range as i don't know the column with respect to letters, Please help me find a solution for the same.

Thanks in advance

for example my code is :

```
Dim Row_num as integer

for x=1 to 100
    Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").range((Row_num,x),(Row_num,x+1)).select
    selection.merge
next
```

Comment: i'm lost, so which column do you want to manipulate? last column? or somewhere in between? not so clear if you ask me.

Comment: Both Rows and Columns start from 1. ie, Column A is 1, Column AA is 27.

Comment: you know you can use cells to define a range? I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the merge though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to chris' excellent answer, let me add two small but really helpful methods of the `Range` object: `.Offset` and `.Resize`:

With `Range.Offset` you can "move" a cell, i.e. `Range("A1").Offset(3, 2)` will result in `B3`. And `.Resize` will will do as the name says, resize the range, i.e. `Range("A1").Resize(3, 2)` will result in `A1:B3`.

Both elements can be combined, e.g. `Range("A1").Offset(1, 1).Resize(3, 2)` results in `B2:C4`.

In your case, you could use:

```
Option Explicit 'always use Option Explicit, as it forces you to declare variables

Sub MergeFields
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim rngTopLeft As Range

    Set rngTopLeft = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'change A1 accordingly!

    For lngRow = 1 To 100
        rngTopLeft.Offset(lngRow).Resize(1, 2).Merge
    Next lngRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct Usage is:

```
<WorkBook>.<WorkSheet>.Range(<CornerCell>, <OpositeCornerCell>)
```

There are several other issues in your code fragment.  See comments in this code

```
Dim Row_num as Long ' Use Long as there may be more than 32767 rows, and its faster
Dim x as Long ' Dim all your variables

With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Use With so you can refer to this part repeatedly
    For x = 1 to 100 Step 2 ' Maybe you meant every second cell, otherwise ranges will overlap
        ' Refer to two corners of the required Range
        ' Don't use Select 
        Range(.Cells(Row_num, x), .Cells(Row_num, x + 1)).Merge
    Next
End With
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the OP wants to select 2 distinct cells, but not a matrix

Comment: @sam092  I think you are wrong.  He wants to merge two adjacent cells.